# Trigger stopping appointments on a Sunday

Tags: sql, database, date, database-trigger

I need to write a trigger to stop users from booking appointments on a Sunday.
After setting a constraint to do this I realised that my coursework asks for it to be done with a trigger which I have been struggling to get working.

The trigger is currently being accepted without any errors but doesn't do anything when data is entered.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER no_sunday_appointments
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Appointment
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    AppointmentDate   DATE;
BEGIN
     IF (trim(TO_CHAR(AppointmentDate,'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY')
     THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100,
     'No Appointments Allowed On A Sunday');
 END IF;
END;
```

I have tried various changes such as not using the trim or using not like 'SUNDAY%' instead of = with no effect, or adding `:new.` before the trim `TO_CHAR` and `AppointmentDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to access `AppointmentDate` in the table being modified.  You have `AppointmentDate` declared as a variable and don't set its value -- so the value remains `NULL`.  So:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER no_sunday_appointments
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Appointment
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF (trim(TO_CHAR(:new.AppointmentDate, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY') THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'No Appointments Allowed On A Sunday');
     END IF;
END;
```

If it is not in the table directly, you might need the variable to calculate it.

Comment: thats great thanks :)     
the only reason i added the declare was because i was getting an error message saying that the value wasnt declared     
it apears to be working correctly now

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER not_on_sunday
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON ACCOUNT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
appointment DATE;
BEGIN
IF (appointment,'DAY')='SUNDAY' THEN
dbms_output.put_line('No Appointments on sunday')


END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).